# Package breqn is broken since MiKTeX removed package mh

Tags: breqn

I just updated my MiKTeX 2.9 installation and the package `mh` was removed as is outdated. Now the package `breqn` won't compile. Whenever I compile my document with `breqn` active, I'm prompted to download the package `mh`, which obviously isn't available since it's outdated. If I continue to compile, an emergency stop occurs and the error `File cmbase.sym not found` is thrown.

Any suggestions on how to use `breqn`?

My MWE...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
foo-bar
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/wspr/breqn/issues/4) which has been fixed in the CTAN release and thus will propagate to MiKTeX and TeX Live as they update. Essentially, in making some other admin changes a mistake was made in the list of files to send to CTAN: this can happen and tends to be picked up quickly. If you absolutely cannot wait until the update is available in your TeX system then you'll need to download the [release code from CTAN](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/breqn) and extract/install the missing file yourself. (To do that, grab `flexisym.dtx` and run `tex flexisym.dtx` to do the extracting, then look at [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows).)